# How to use get std::bind like behaviour

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am trying to write a wrapper for std::bind.  My first attempt is:

```
typedef std::function<void(float, int)> tCallback;

template<typename F, class... Args>
tCallback mybind(F f, Args... args)
{
    return std::tr1::bind( f, Args... args, 
        std::tr1::placeholders::_1, std::tr1::placeholders::_2 );
}
```

Given something like:

```
struct Foo {
   tCallback m__cb;
   setcb(tCallback cb) {m_cb = cb;}
   ....
};

void f1(float f, int i) {}
void f2(int j, float f, int i) {}

Foo foo;
foo.setcb( mybind( f1 ) );   // Fine.
foo.setcb( mybind( f2, 1 ) ); // Not fine.
```

What am I doing wrong?  On Visual Studio, the error refers to Args starting with "int &" (which surprises me, but I may be down a few layers of error message).  On GCC the error refers to "too many arguments".  (I am not naive enough to expect helpful error messages from deeply templated code like this!)

Do I need to write versions of mybind for function pointers and member function pointers (and what do I do about functors)?

Note: I'm using VS2015 and GCC 4.9, so the std::bind and placeholders are in tr1.

Comment: "I'm using VS2015 and GCC 4.9, so the std::bind and placeholders are in tr1." Wait, what?

Comment: And `bind( f, Args... args, /*...*/)` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: What is the purpose of writing a "wrapper"?

Comment: @Pete Becker:  The normal use case is that the callable the client application wishes to invoke has a small number of arguments they wish to bind (often just a 'this' pointer), plus the arguments of the callback.  The real code actually has four arguments, and the explicit call to std::bind looks rather messy in the client code.  I think mybind(f,1) is less opaque than std::bind(f,1,std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);

Comment: Yes, thanks. I overlooked the placeholders in the forwarding call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting errors because of the `Args... args` which should be just `args...` as mentioned in the comments already.

Also consider to use `std::forward` to forward your parameters correctly and
prefer to use `decltype` to determine the return type of your wrapper function
which doesn't force convertion into a `std::function`:

```
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<void(float, int)> tCallback;

template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto mybind(F f, Args... args)
    -> decltype(std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...,
        std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 ))
//      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
{
    return std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)..., 
//      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^~~~~
        std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 );
}

struct Foo {
   tCallback m_cb;
   void setcb(tCallback cb) {m_cb = cb;}
};

void f1(float f, int i) {}
void f2(int j, float f, int i) {}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.setcb( mybind( f1 ) );   // Fine.
    foo.setcb( mybind( f2, 1 ) ); // Not fine.
}
```

**[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e744bf3d8f0ebfbd)**

---

Just a quick note about the note :-)

> Note: I'm using VS2015 and GCC 4.9, so the std::bind and placeholders are in tr1.

`std::bind` was moved in the std namespace from Visual Studio 2013(2012) and
should be preffered over the tr1 namespace.

Comment: You probably miss the forwarding references for `mybind(F&& f, Args&&... args)`, else just use `std::move`

Comment: 1.  The Args... was entirely bogus, and down to me posting from home without the code in front of me.  Sorry about that.

Comment: 2.  VS2015 is quite happy with bind and placeholders in std ... and so is GCC.  The existing code has been using std::tr1 - I have no idea why.

Comment: I don't particularly want to use decltype because the whole point of this function is to simplify the generation of the argument to setcb (which takes a tCallback).  (The fact that not using the decltype reduces the noise is just an added bonus.)

Comment: I am going to accept this answer because: a) it clarified the syntax for using std::forward for me (which I knew I really ought to do, but I just didn't quite know how).  b) Working through this found my actual problem.

Comment: You know I said I had typed this away from work?  If I had copy and pasted in my actual code, I suspect most people would have spotted that: 
  return std::tr1::bind( f, Args... args, 
        std::tr1::placeholders::_1, std::tr1::placeholders::_2, std::tr1::placeholders::_2 );
Looks rather suspicious.   Apologies for all the noise :-(

Answer (score 0):

So the actual problem was that

```
return std::tr1::bind( f, Args... args, 
    std::tr1::placeholders::_1, std::tr1::placeholders::_2 );
```

was actually:

```
return std::tr1::bind( f, args..., 
    std::tr1::placeholders::_1, 
    std::tr1::placeholders::_2, std::tr1::placeholders::_2 );
```

The "Args... args" vs "args..." was me misremembering my code.  The doubled _2 meant I was trying to call a function with the wrong number of arguments.  (I don't understand why it worked with zero bind args, but that's a different question!)